# getStorage() on null when using entityTypeManager in form

Tags: forms, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use dependency injection correctly in a custom form but I'm getting an error when trying to access entityTypeManager.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\my_module\Service\AliasCsvParser;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a my_module form.
 */
class myModuleImportForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   */
  public function __construct(
    EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
  ) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $form = new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_module_import';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['path_alias_csv'] = [
      '#type' => 'my_module_managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Alias import csv'),
      '#description' => $this->t('upload a csv file containing at least the following 3 columns "id, alias, langcode"'),
      '#upload_location' => 'private://my_module_import',
      '#upload_validators' => [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['csv'],
        '_validate_alias_csv' => [],
      ],
    ];

    $form['results'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'parse-results',
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Import aliases'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['visually-hidden']],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $csv_field = $form_state->getValue('path_alias_csv');
    $parser = new AliasCsvParser(reset($csv_field));
    $parser->saveAliasFromCsv();
    if (TRUE) {
      $file = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load(reset($csv_field));
      $file->setPermanent();
      $file->save();
    }

  }

}
```

I get the error
`Call to a member function getStorage() on null in`
on this line
`$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load(reset($csv_field));`
So I think the class isn't being initialised correctly and `$entityTypeManager` is null but I don't know why.

Cheers Dan

Answer (score -1):

I was incorrectly trying to chain function calls

This works.

```
$file_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file');
$file = $file_storage->load(reset($csv_field));
$file->setPermanent();
$file->save();
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Rewriting the code is not necessary and won't prevent the error. The question why $entityTypeManager was null is still unclear.

Comment: *Call to a member function getStorage() on null* just means that `$this->entityTypeManager` is `null`. Since this code doesn't verify `$this->entityTypeManager` isn't `null`, the same error will be shown for it too.